# Replace all Line Breaks from an EXCEL File with C#

Tags: c#, excel, cell

I am using C# on Visual Studio and have struggled with replacing the line breaks of the excel file.

I have tried the following commands, none of them can replace all the line breaks which exist in a cell of excel. (Even using all of them, there are still line breaks show as "LF" in Notepad++.)

```
answer = Regex.Replace(answer, @"\r\n?|\n", "<br>");
answer = answer.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br>");
answer = answer.Replace("\\n", "<br>");
answer = answer.Replace("\n", "<br>");
answer = answer.Replace("\r\n", "<br>");
answer = answer.Replace("\r", "<br>");
```

An example of the original cell looks like this:

> [Blockquote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuJe1.png)

Afterward the cell looks like this:

> [after replacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp1a7.png)

I expect that there should be no line breaks shown as "LF" in Notepad++, but with the mentioned code, there are still a few "LF"s.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post `answer` content before and after? As hex dumps.

Comment: How do you get the value from the excel sheet and how does the string look before replacing the values? I think your code should actually work.

Comment: Oh, Sinatr was faster. ;)

Comment: Off-topic: did you know you could chain the method calls? I.e. `answer = answer.Replace(...).Replace(...).Replace...`

Comment: You have to change property of excell cells.   Select entire worksheet.  the from menu Home : Format : Format Cells : Alignment : Wrpa Text.  Uncheck the box.  You can do this from code as well and use select cells instead of entire worksheet.

Comment: this might help : [whats the equivalent for line feed in c#](https://forums.asp.net/t/1297449.aspx?whats+the+equivalent+for+line+feed+in+c+)

Comment: @tukaef Yes I have replaced them with concatinated one, each line with one replace is just to see the effect easier

Comment: @jdweng Do you mean I should modify the cell settings inside the excel?

Comment: @Mohamed Thanks for the link. It's not working unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you all!
@Sinatr, aYo: an example of before-after is added. The cell is extracted through: (range.Cells[i, j] as Excel.Range).Value2;

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do from your description.  Are you trying to reformat the excel worksheet or just use the output from the worksheet.  You are using .Value2 and maybe using .Text will be better.

Comment: Unfortunately the updated content in your question won't help us. We need to know which hidden characters are in this string. When you set a breakpoint in VS, and look at the content in the watch window, what exactly do you see there? Line breaks for example would normally be displayed as \r\n or \n. So what exactly is the value before and after your replacement? By the way, you are using EPPlus to read the excel, right?

Comment: Ah I see this is not EPPlus, but probably the MS thing. Maybe the Value property gives you an escaped string and line breaks are displayed as &#10; for example. Anyway, whatever it is, we will see it in the watch window.

Comment: I just tried it myself now. The properties Value2 and Text both contain the the same value: "FirstLine\nSecondLine". When I run cell.Value2 = cell.Value2.Replace("\n", "<br>"); the line break is properly replaced . So for now I can't reproduce the problem and need more information to be able to help you.